# How to add Submenu to Tabulator Context Menu?

Tags: tabulator

I am trying add a submenu to decrease the height of a rather long menu. I looked at Menu module documentation but could not find any clues

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no way to do this built in to Tabulator.

If you would like to see it as a feature, please create a [Feature Request](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Suggested+Feature&template=feature_request.md&title=) and provide details of the functionality you are after